# Casting argument before using reflection to invoke a method

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I try to using reflection to set a value from A model to B model

```
   // Get value in Board model using dynamic getter
   Object lvBoardValue;
   // Value after invoke getter is (Double)
   lvBoardValue = lvBoardPropDesc.getReadMethod().invoke(pBoardModel);
   // Return type of getter in Instrument  => (int)
   Class lvInstReturnType = lvInstrumentPropDesc.getReadMethod().getReturnType();
   // Return type of getter in Board => (double)
   Class lvBoardReturnType = lvBoardPropDesc.getReadMethod().getReturnType();
                
   // set that value for instrument (This setter need int value)
   lvInstrumentPropDesc.getWriteMethod().invoke(pBaseModel, (int) lvBoardValue);
```

**The problem is I want to set a Double value (lvBoardValue) by invoking another setter which is need int value. I googled a lot the way to cast from Double to int, but have no clue.**

I have tried:

```
lvInstrumentPropDesc.getWriteMethod().invoke(pBaseModel, ((Double) lvBoardValue).intValue());
```

It should work by casting like that, but it cannot meet the requirement of setting dynamically if I could have a return type

Have anyone already face this situation?. Please give me a suggestion. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You wanted to set a double value in place of an int setter?? why can't can't you cast the double to int in an Integer and use that to setter??

Comment: The value is an Double object, not primitive value.

Comment: Can you rephrase the “it cannot meet the requirement of setting dynamically if I could have a return type”?

Comment: I dont want to manually casting because I based on getReturnType() to get the type of a getter in Model A, and I want to use it for casting in Model B if not compatible

Comment: getSomething() in Model A -> Return Double value -> Use it for  setSomething(int pParam) in Model B. All steps should be done by code thanks to reflection, so need a way to cast dynamically not in manual way.

Comment: You can use `((Number)lvBoardValue).intValue()`. Besides that, there is no “casting” for arbitrary types.